# Sharpening blades in blender

Tags: edges, subdivision-surface

I have a blade that visually appears extremely low poly, however, when I attempt to apply effects like subdivision surface, it seems to just make it smoother and less sharp, even when set to simple. Any way to procedurally sharpen it or make it less low poly? I want to reduce the edges along the blade so that it appears more similar to an actual axe
Images:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Subdivision Surface modifier and Smooth Shading very often require _Supporting Geometry_ to make them look "proper". Additionally, you can select the edges you want "sharp" right click and select "edge crease - drag the mouse until they look "sharp" enough.